# unbalanced panel and multidimensional array in Winbugs

Tags: arrays, winbugs

I have a model for input demand, with unbalanced data. The dependent variable is `yijt`, where `i` means input of production function `(i=1,2,3)`, `j` means firm `(j=1,..,21)`,  and `t` means time `(ti=1,..,Ti)`.  So, because the panel is unbalanced, with three equations, what could be the correct format to use it in winbugs?

I tried to use it in shape of STATA long format,  3*107, where indexes are a bit different. Row (`i`) means an input and columns (`j`) form a panel `i*t`. So, no explicit time index. I used nested indexing for columns, to form data as a panel. Little piece of code:

```
for (i in 1:3){
     for(j in 1:107){
          log(mu[i,j]) <- a[i]+ u[firm[j]]+...
```

where `a[i]` is an input-specific free parameter, `u` is a desired firm-specific error component, which should be estimated over firms (21). For this I use nested indexing, where expression of u in the model is over columns `u[firm[j]]` and prior for `u` is over firms `u[k]`.

Here is the question about nested indexing. **If the model includes many covariates, which are also time-dependent, should I use nested indexing for all of these covariates, otherwise Winbugs does not take it as a panel?**

I tried to use a multidimensional array for all multidimensional variables. For balancing a lot of NA-s were included. For example, dependent variable yijt is an 3-dimensional array `y[ , , ]`, (using list command), but in some reason Winbugs didn`t recognize NA-s? 
Main point is that posterior distribution does not converge, and data formatting could be one of the reasons

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off to keep the data in a long format (with columns for y, i, j and t) and rows for each response (which will have NA for y where you have missing data).

The Center for Multilevel Modelling have a good introductory guide on running these types of models in this format with WinBUGS [[here]](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/mmsoftware/winbugs.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Long format is very convenient, but seems not working for my model. It could be that I don`t understand the logic behind Winbugs and panel data. In case of two indexes, column index changes faster than row index? If it does, then rows must be the inputs, and for every input, all columns must be counted. All variables are located in separate matrices. And nested indexing is for distinguishing companies, between columns.That is, what I need for correct model. But I am not sure, because posterior is not converging. Perhaps Winbugs has different logic for panel?

Comment: can you explain a little more why long format does not work? i have gone down your road before (with many indices). i found things became a lot lot easier with the long data format.

Comment: I agree, long format is ok for a single equation models. But how to organize data in a long format for 3-dimensional model, with 2 indices? If the first is a row index, then it means 3 rows (3 inputs), so columns must be over firms and time. It is a wide format. Or is there any other solution?